# lottie animation gets recomposed when i scroll which is inside the lazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lottie, composable

I am creating a stack animation that contains a list of animations. The animation is inside a LazyColumn, and when I scroll, the LazyColumn gets recomposed. However, the Lottie animation also gets recomposed or called, which starts from the beginning. How can I prevent the animation from recomposing when I scroll?

```
@Composable
fun Container(context: Context) {
val items = remember { List(10) { "Item $it" } }
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = Color.White)
        .fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
        Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(200.dp, 500.dp)
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 12.dp))
                .background(color = Color(0xFF82D8FF)),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                items(3) {
                    println("Recomposition")
                    Loader()
                  }
              }
          }
      }
   }
}

@Composable
fun Loader() {
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.water_loading))
val progressAsState by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
    composition = composition,
    clipSpec = LottieClipSpec.Progress(0f, 1f),
)

 LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
    progress = { progressAsState },
    modifier = Modifier.requiredHeight(350.dp),
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight
   )
}
```

I just want the animation to be unaffected by any compostion or scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. You can use Column in a for loop instead of using LazyColumn and use Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()).

```
@Composable
fun Container(context: Context) {
    val items = remember { List(10) { "Item $it" } }
    
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color.White)
            .fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(200.dp, 500.dp)
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 12.dp))
                    .background(color = Color(0xFF82D8FF)),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Column(
                    Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    items.forEach{ item ->
                        Loader()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution with loop is not very good, since lazy layouts are specifically designed to improve performance when you need to render list of items.

You can continue to use the `LazyColumn` or `LazyRow` simply by adding a flag variable that will keep its state when changing the configuration and scrolling through the list. For this you need to use `rememberSaveable`

```
// to avoid extra animations when scrolling list of items
var animate by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }
```

and then, set `animate` to false when your animation already done
then use condition with `animate` to choose right animation state

I don't sure about code below, I haven't tested it, but it should look something like this:

```
// to avoid extra animations when scrolling list of items
var animate by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) } 

val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.water_loading))
val animationState = animateLottieCompositionAsState(
    composition = composition,
    clipSpec = LottieClipSpec.Progress(0f, 1f),
)

LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
    progress = if (animate) animationState.progress else 1f, // set progress to 100%
    modifier = Modifier.requiredHeight(350.dp),
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight
   )

if (logoAnimationState.isAtEnd) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        // when the animation has already played, 
        // sets to false to avoid re-animating when scrolling
        animate = false 
    }
}
```